# What is the meaning of the first P in the acronym for Hypertext Processor, PHP?

Tags: php, acronym

PHP (recursive acronym for PHP: Hypertext Processor) is a widely-used open source general-purpose scripting language that is especially suited for dynamic web development and can be embedded into HTML...

And that's all I got from the web, W3Schools, Wikipedia, Stack Overflow and even my lecturers at the University.

Can anyone tell me what exactly the P stands for or why it doesn't follow the meaning of PHP and/or why hasn't it been removed?

Comment: P -> PHP. It's a recursive acronym... just like the description you've included says ....

Comment: PHP originally stood for **Personal Home Page** See [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)

Comment: Recursive acronym. PHP Hypertext Processor. first P literally means PHP. Like WINE - WINE Is Not an Emulator. or GNU - GNU Not Unix

Comment: God bless you @B001....this is beginning to sound like it.

Comment: @B001ᛦ, maybe it still does, I guess.

Comment: @pasignature no.. no it still doesn't ... just read the docs it's all right there :'(

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thank you loads for the edit. Beautiful.

Comment: @treyBrake, pls share if you have a link. thanks

Comment: @pasignature https://php.net -> the official docs... just google php

Comment: @treyBake, been there, seen that link.....there is nothing there that explains the P. It just repeats the same thing we've known for years....but "B001ᛦ" and "José Antonio Font" comments really made sense to me.  I just deduced my answer from those comments and thats enough for me. I guess that's what Stack Overflow is meant for. You dont have to get a super perfect answer, a clue is enough.

Comment: @pasignature https://secure.php.net/manual/en/intro-whatis.php -> PHP (recursive acronym for PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor) literally first line is the P.... Jose's answer parrots this .. SO provides answers that are perfect or else what's the point.. clues are done via comments?

Comment: You must remember that the concern here is just the first P...your links have nothing explaining the P.....

Comment: @pasignature yes it does - try reading the brackets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It used to stand for Personal Home Page; however, as it grew to be a bit more than a scripting/templating language for simple projects, its meaning was changed to PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor. The first 'P' now stands for PHP itself.

Comment: This really bothers me...shouldn't it be 'HHP'? If it's recursive for 'H'ypertext 'P'reprocessor...or is it tail recursive. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It literally means PHP, it is a *recursive acronym* in which the actual word is one of the letters.

Just like GNU means: **GNU is Not Unix**.

Comment: No.... it is not!

Comment: @B001ᛦ it is -> according to php.net. Even if the original meaning meant something else, it's current meaning does mean PHP

Comment: @treyBake, I already extracted my answer from two beautiful souls B001ᛦ...and José Antonio Font

Comment: @pasignature well b001 answer isn't actually an answer ...

Comment: yes, thats why I didnt accept it, I only used it as clue.